# What is the historical origin of purple as a color indicating poison in Japanese visual media?

Tags: japan, media

In videogames and anime, purple is often the color of poison.  For example, if a blade is shown with a purple fluid on it it will be obvious to anyone familiar with such works that it is poison-coated.  The actual compound the poison is comprised of will generally not be discussed - poison is poison is poison.

I am curious about the origin as purple as the color of choice.  So far, I've found two claims:

1. Bright purple fluids are not naturally found among food or drink and the choice was otherwise arbitrary and caught on (starting when?)
2. [The Arsenic Act 1851](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenic_Act_1851), a UK law, required arsenic to be dyed with indigo

Both of these appeared to be idle speculation, but at least the second cited an actual law.  In fact, the first claim could have been the reason for choosing indigo as a dye.  Yet neither point to the first depiction of purple poison in Japanese or Eastern-in-general media.  Is there some record of when poison first started being depicted as purple?  I know of modern depictions, but not if purple meant poison in older literature or sketches.  Nor do I know if an UK law from the 1850s could have influenced the color association in Japan.  I do know the 1850s were at least [the time period](https://www.britannica.com/place/Japan/The-opening-of-Japan) when Japan resumed trading with western nations.

Mind you, I will not be shocked if I do not receive a definitive answer to my query.  Speculation is fine, if it points to actual laws, trade, depictions, etc.  Likewise, older-than-anime depictions of purple poison in media at least get me closer to when this started.

Comment: I would've said that fluorescent green rather than purple is the "poison color" for video games and anime. What is the earliest "purple poison" you can think of? Or a few examples of what you mean across the years?

Comment: "Radioactive green" is indeed the other major poison/toxin color.  For purple in video games, an example would be Pokemon.  Mario has a purple poisonous mushroom.  For purple in anime, the most recent example I saw was from 7th Time Loop.  A quick search for lists of anime characters who use poison will return examples of purple-coded and greed-coded characters.  I struggle to think of the oldest example I have encountered in either category though.  Certainly both are minimally decades old.